# Why does clearInterval and clearTimeout make the self-increment slower?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clearinterval, cleartimeout

It works well as I was able to stop when the certain limit is being met through the iteration.

But I wonder why when I tried to delay the time of execution of setInterval, the increment of progressBar becomes slower.

Increasing the delay time of either setInterval or setTimeout would affect the speed to slower.

What I wanted is delay the execution by 5 secs, and the increment speed is 1 per second.

```
    const [progressBar, setProgressBar] = React.useState(0);
    let timeout;
    let interval;
    React.useEffect(
        () => {
            timeout = setTimeout(() =>{
                if(progressBar === 100){
                    return clearTimeout(timeout);
                } else{
                    interval = setInterval(() =>{
                       if(progressBar === 100){
                            clearInterval(interval);
                       } else{
                        setProgressBar(prev_value => prev_value + 1);
                       }
                    },10);
                }
            }, 10);
            return () => {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                clearInterval(interval);
                
            };
    }, [progressBar]);

    let divStyle = {
      backgroundColor: "green",
      width: "100px",
      maxWidth: `${progressBar}px`,
      border: "1px solid red"
    }
```

JSX

```
<div className='progress-bar' style={divStyle}>{progressBar}</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you may be starting more interval timers than you think you are.

Comment: @Pointy I am sorry, do you mean add more interval? I would like to ask for advice on how can I solve this problem. Rookie here btw ^^

Comment: you have `progressBar` in `useEffect` dependency. when `setProgressBar` runs, `progressBar` will change its value and then `useEffect` will run again creating infinite loop.

Comment: @Layhout I see. I was able to run it with `setInterval` without `setTimeout` in a code.  But I just wonder how am I supposed to delay the execute That's the only thing left for me to satisfy my needs for this to be run. What can I do to do that? Thank you!

Comment: i think you just remove `progressBar` from `useEffect` dependency and your code will work as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use hook error, if you using setState inside react, that will be re exec that function again in react world.

so your interval always run 1 time cause you destory that in destroy call back,

once you setState that will be triggered based on your `useEffect` deps,

I think you should write that like that.
not need any deps and only clear that interval when that value become what you want.

maybe that will be helpful.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-any9su?file=App.tsx

Comment: Thank you @ZouAlan! How am I delay the execution of it without using `setTimeout`? I really appreciate if there is any reference I could read for this.

Comment: Do you mean trigger that when the user do some action?

if you need wait some time before exec that, you still can using setTimeout to do to that in react

Comment: No. I am planning to use the delay for animation. Execution of the first animation before this progress bar. I would like to but once I combined together, the count become slower.